# How do I blow away Thunderbird's email/password settings?

Tags: thunderbird

Am running 12.04 w/latest version of Thunderbird.

I use Thunderbird as an offline backup of Gmail/Goolge Apps. I recently made an account change in Google so that the stored credentials don't match. I no longer am able to get Thunderbird running. Is there a way of modifying the email account information outside of Thunderbird, or wiping what's in there w/o completely blowing away my profile and starting from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to start `Thunderbird` with the "safe-mode" option by entering in the terminal `thunderbird -safe-mode`, which sometimes allows one to start the program when it won't start normally. This is effectively a debug mode which makes `Thunderbird` start without addons disabled and with only the most basic configuration options enabled.

Alternatively, you could find your `.thunderbird` folder in your home folder by viewing hidden files in your file explorer. Then you should be able to navigate to the various folders, although you won't be able to access the stored passwords as they are kept encrypted in sqlite databases. So **backup** your profile first if you want, then navigate to `.thuderbird/<profile.default>/` then delete `signons.sqlite` and `key3.db` to remove your passwords and logins. This only removes the passwords, but it will be enough to get `Thunderbird` running again if my first method fails.

[image]